# JQuery Rails included twice. How to fix?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using two different layout in my rails project. 
I have already downloaded jquery and place it in a file and included in guest layout file.(guest.js). Name of layout is **guest** 
like this

```
//= require guest/my_folder/core.min.js
```

Now the problem is i have defined following in my application

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require_tree
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require jquery.validate
//= require select2
```

But some of jquery/javascrit stop working in my application. I presume its due to duplicated jquery, but cannot figure out how to fix it I tried removing core.min.js(jquery) file, but facing issue if i remove this file.
Please help

Comment: Why did you think downloading a separate copy of jquery was a good idea in the first place? Just use the gemified version provided by jquery rails. In general downloading/copying css/js libs is an outmoded practice and a maintainence problem and you should use the gemified versions when possible.

Comment: Yes you are right, but other developer do it like this. How can i remove it now. What lines should i include in guest.js file?

Comment: //= require jquery

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have downloaded jquery and placed in one of your folder under assets/javascripts

So In your case you need to remove this line from your js file

```
//= require_tree
```

Comment: I try removing this line, but if i remove this line then validations stop working on jquery level, as i have used jquery-validation gem

Comment: If you are using jquery-validation gem then you can add the jquery.validate manually. Try adding //= require jquery.validate to the js file